# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException to receive a udp packet when Windows Phone app in background

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

My app always runs a thread for trying to receive Udp packet from server in a loop. This works fine when app is in foreground. But when start button is pressed and app goes to background then it throws System.Net.Sockets.SocketException. But I want the app to receive packet when it is in background too. How?

Answer (score 0):

All sockets will be terminated when your app is suspended, which is what happens when you press the Windows button.

It is not possible to create a Windows Phone application which can send and receive over sockets when running in the background.